# Stdin automatically open in Rstudio?

Tags: r, command-line, rstudio

If I type the following in my command line:

```
Rscript -e "isatty(stdin())"
```

I get:

```
TRUE
```

If I type the following into RStudio:

```
isatty(stdin())
```

I get:

```
FALSE
```

Does RStudio keep stdin open automatically? Seems wrong...

Comment: Have you read the Details section of `?isatty`?

Comment: Is there a better way?

Comment: A better way to do what?